# SKMapView initWithFrame: crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, skmaps

Here is the code of my map initialization:

```
SKMapView *mapView = [[SKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100, 100)];
[self.view addSubview:mapView];
```

And here is the result :((

[image: XCode stack trace screenshot]

Pls any help?

Comment: libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.5.10 but running with 1.6.16

Here is the log. Dunno how to fix it

Comment: This question was reported to the Scout developers

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in the demo project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
One of 3rd party library added to the project wrong version of pnglib.
After removing this lib, SKMaps using the system pnglib without any problems.